# Jquery on Master Page

Tags: jquery

I have just started working on Jquery as i am beginner ,i am implementing jquery on master page.The function of this jquery is to display multiple images on division and it is working successfully.
   The problem that i am facing is when i click on menu control and page navigate the jquery function doesn't work.

Here is Code which is not working

```
 $(window).load(function () {
            var i = 0;
            var images = ['M2.jpg', 'M3.jpg', 'M4.jpg', 'M5.jpg', 'M6.jpg', 'M7.jpg'];
            var image = $('#divleftImg'); 
            image.css("background-image", "url('Images/M1.jpg')");
            setInterval(function () {
                image.fadeOut(1000, function () {
                    image.css('background-image', 'url(Images/' + images[i++] + ')');
                    image.fadeIn(1000);
                }
                );
                if (i == images.length)
                    i = 0;
            }, 5000);
        });
```

And the other jquery function is working properly which displays multiple text on single Div, even on page navigate it is working properly

Here is the code

```
$(document).ready(function ()
    {
        $(window).load(function ()
        {
            $('#1').hide();
            $('#2').hide();
            $('#3').hide();
            var i = 1;
            $('divMultipleText').css('background:linear-gradient(gray,blue)');
            setInterval(function ()
            {
                i++;
                if (i == 10)
                {
                    $('#1').show();
                    $('#2').hide();
                    $('#3').hide();

                }
                if (i == 20)
                {
                    $('#1').hide();
                    $('#2').show();
                    $('#3').hide();
                }
                if (i == 30)
                {
                    $('#1').hide();
                    $('#2').hide();
                    $('#3').show();
                    i = 0;
                }
            },100);

        });
    });
```

Please Help me out. I have placed div on td element and it is backcolor is Black can it be a problem.

Comment: Where is actual problem ? your Code is amazing!

Comment: Actual problem is ,my jquery image function is on Master Page ie MainPage.master,when i navigate to another page ie Page1.aspx the function stop working,but when i navigate to Home the function gets exectued,why it is happening ,because master page is already loaded.

Comment: Check if this javascript Still displaying in Browser on Another PAGE.

Comment: Yes is Showing ,by seeing View Source.

Comment: No Console Error,and i am running it on IE browser which always throw Java script error.But the other function is working properly.

Comment: It is not showing any error on IE browser working properly except that function.